# Any alternates of INT_MAX and INT_MIN?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is this number (1e9) less than the INT_MAX value and (-1e9) greater than the INT_MIN value?

So, whenever I need to use in my program, some big positive number or smallest negative number, I use INT_MAX or INT_MIN in general but when there are some constraints in some cases like no use of header files to write your program, in that situation, can I use (1e9) and (-1e9) as the largest and smallest number?

Comment: Have you tried to print the values of `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`? On your target platform, what is the size of `int`? How many bits is it? Is your target platform using one- or two-complement for representing negative values?

Comment: The C++ standard allows `int` to be as small as 16 bits, in which case `INT_MAX` could be as small as 32767 and `1e9` would overflow an `int`.

Comment: INT_MAX = 2147483647 and size of int = 4 byte @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @NateEldredge in my compiler, size of int is 32 bits and INT_MAX = 2147483647 so I think, 1e9 should be less than INT_MAX

Comment: "no use of header files" - that's stupid. Can't even `std::cout` anything then. Even the most constrained systems (freestanding), who may not have `<iostream>` must still have `<climits>`. A compiler without `<climits>` simply is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @codosopher: Not my vote, but it's enough of a challenge to answer C++ questions. Questions about a language that is vaguely C++-like are generally not well received. You can't answer them properly. Tagging it not just C++, but even specifically C++17  makes it extra weird: you're at the same time being very specific about which C++ standard you mean, yet the C++17 standard too includes `<climits>`. If you had asked about a missing `<version>` header, that makes sense; that is new in C++20, but `<climits>` has always been on C++

Comment: On a typical system with a 32-bit `int`, `INT_MIN` is (typically) either `-2147483647` or `-2147483648` (both of which are less than `-1e9`) and `INT_MAX` is either `2147483647` or `2147483648`which (which both exceed `1e9`).    However, the standard only guarantees that `INT_MIN` is no more than `-32767` and `INT_MAX` is no less than `32767` (corresponding to a 16-bit `int`).   There are (older) systems that do only provide a 16-bit `int`, so using `-1e9` and `1e9` as lower/upper bounds for an `int` is inappropriate in general.

Comment: @Peter got it. finally you get my point. thanks for your answer. Do you think, on a 32 bit system, can I use it as upper/lower bound?

Comment: @codosopher  Not all 32-bit systems have a 32-bit `int`, so no - although you might get lucky.   32-bit refers to how data is addressed, not size of the native integral type.

Comment: @peter most of my compilers in my system, size of int is 4 bytes so in this situation I can use 1e9 and -1e9 as upper bound and lower bound in my program, right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is 1e9 less than INT_MAX value from the header file climits?

It can be. It isn't necessarily. It depends on the target system.

> Is -1e9 greater than INT_MIN value from the header file climits?

Same as above.

Since `int` isn't guaranteed to be sufficient, you should use at least `long` type, or the more specific aliases from `<cstdint>` header which are at least 32 bits wide if you need numbers in the range of [-1e9,1e9].

Comment: Well I need some big number to store in a variable inside my program for solving some problems and if there's no use of header files, then I can use 1e9 as a big positive integer if size of int is 32 bits in my compiler, right

Comment: @codosopher Why not use the actual maximum?

Comment: I mean, in theoretical sense to build a logic of that problem in pen n paper, I would consider infinity as a maximum number so that I can find minimum value in the logic. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `long` instead, then the answer to both questions you pose is yes.

Its minimum range prior to C++20 is -2147483647 to +2147483647 which is large enough. (Cf. an `int` which has a minimum range of -32767 to +32767.)

Out of interest, from C++20 onwards the minimum is -2147483648 and signed integral types become simpler to work with.